# Optimizing string analysis using slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently taking back Python after over 6 years I do not use it, and to do that I am solving some small challenges on Hacker Rank. I wrote a code that works, but which is not performant and I would like to have some ideas to optimize it.

### Problem statement

Given a certain string, count how many anagrams are possible for that string.
The anagrams are those substrings for which the letters used are the same.
For example, if we take the string `mama`, we have 5 possible anagrams:

1. The first `m` with the third `m`
2. The second `a` with the fourth `a`
3. The first `ma` with the second `ma`
4. The first `ma` with the middle `am`
5. The middle `am` with the last `ma`

My function should count the number of anagrams for a given string.

### Current (working) code

I've come up with the below code which works always as expected (note: I'm adding the `__main__` as well so that you can copy-paste and run the code in any IDLE):
(disclaimer: if you want to understand the logic without reading the code, I've added a "logic" section just after the code snippet).

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the sherlockAndAnagrams function below.
def sherlockAndAnagrams(s):
    nb = 0
    stringSize = len(s)
    for size in range(1, len(s)):
        for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
            ss = s[i:i+size]
            for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
                if j+size <= stringSize:
                    ss2 = s[j:j+size]
                    if haveSameLetters(ss, ss2):
                        nb += 1
    return nb
        
def haveSameLetters(s1,s2):
    s1Map = getMapOfLetters(s1)
    s2Map = getMapOfLetters(s2)
    return areMapEquals(s1Map, s2Map)

def areMapEquals(m1, m2):
    if len(m1) != len(m2):
        return False
    for k,v in m1.items():
        if not m2.__contains__(k):
            return False
        else:
            if m2.get(k) != v:
                return False
    return True

def getMapOfLetters(s):
    sMap = {}
    for letter in s:
        if sMap.__contains__(letter):
            sMap[letter] = sMap.get(letter)+1
        else:
            sMap[letter] = 1
    return sMap

if __name__ == '__main__':

    s1 = "kkkk"
    print("Expect 10, received ", sherlockAndAnagrams(s1))
    s2 = "ifailuhkqq"
    print("Expect 3, received ", sherlockAndAnagrams(s2))
    s3 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    print("Expect 166650, received ", sherlockAndAnagrams(s3))
```

### Logic in words

With this code, I analyze blocks of substrings. First, I analyze each substring of size `1`, then of size `2`, then of size `3` etc. until `n-1` (where `n` would be the size of the whole string in input).

Let's take the word `mama` again. What I do is:

The count starts at `0`.

1. I take the first substring of size `1`, which is `m`, and I compare it with the second `a` (`False`), the third `m` (`True`) and the fourth `a` (`False`). The count is now `1`.
2. Then I take the second substring of size `1` which is `a`, and I compare it with the third `m` (`False`) and the fourth `a` (`True`). The count is now `2`.
3. Then I take the third substring of size `1`, which is `m`, and I compare it with the fourth `a` (`False`). The count stays at `2`.
4. Then I move to the first substring of size `2`, which is `ma`, and I compare it with the next substring `am` (`True`) and `ma` (`True`). The count is now `4`.
5. Then I move to the next substring which is `am` and I compare it with the next substring `ma` (`True`). The count is now `5`.
6. Then I move to the first substring of size `3`, which is `mam`, and I compare it with the next substring `ama` (`False`). The count stays at `5`.

At this point, the loop is over and I'm left with the count `5`.

### Optimization

The code works, but it is pretty consuming. For the third example in my code snippet, a string which contains `100` times the letter `a`, the result of the count of possible anagrams is `166,650` and the code needs to make `490,050` iterations before getting to that result.
In the case of that `100 a's` string, it takes `1.324274` seconds to execute.

I am trying to optimize this code. Any thought or suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Unused Imports

You don't use any of the imports in your code. Remove them.

## `areMapEquals`

Dictionarys can be compared using the `=`

```
def areMapEquals(m1, m2):
    return m1 == m2
```

But at this point, this function is obsolete since you can now make this check in the `hasSameLetters` function. But eventually that function gets obsolete too, since you can do that calculation without a function too.

## Naming

Functions and variables should be in `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

## Counters

Instead of creating a dict yourself, utilize the `collections.Counter` class, which does all of this for you. It also has it's own equal comparison, so you can reduce a lot of your code.

## Looping

Your first loop is just for keeping track of the size. But if you look closely, `size` is always just one more than `i`, so just define size inside the second loop as such. This removes the need for the first loop, greatly increasing performance.

## Reuse variables

You have `stringSize` (which should be `length`) which hold the size of the string, but you still have `len(s)` in your code. Just use that variable.

## Efficient Algorithms

Here's something I wrote a while back that solve this very question:

```
def count_anagrams(string: str) -> int:
    """
    This counts the total amount of anagram substrings, given a string.

    @param str string - String to count anagrams.

    @return int - Number of anagrams.
    """
    n = len(string)
    _map = dict() 
    
    for i in range(n):
        substr = ''
        for j in range(i, n): 
            substr = ''.join(sorted(substr + string[j]))
            _map[substr] = _map.get(substr, 0)
            _map[substr] += 1

    return sum((v * (v - 1)) // 2 for v in _map.values())
```

While this doesn't utilize the `collections.Counter` class, it's still extremely efficient and gets the job done!

Comment: Oh hi I see you also though about the Counter class, it is so useful :)

Comment: @Caridorc Yep! I saw OP counting in a dict and immediately thought of it :).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I work daily in Java and just used Python for few months a long while ago. With a single answer you optimized the code and gave me very good tips to refresh the language in my mind (naming, Counter, in...)... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

#### `Counter` class from collections

You are just re-implementing the `Counter` class from collections so you can just use:

```
from collections import Counter
```

at the start, and then:

```
def areMapEquals(m1, m2):
    return m1 == m2

getMapOfLetters = Counter
```

Of course you can just do this inline because these are just a few simple operations.

On my machine using the built-ins also nets an about 10% speed-up.

---

A minor point is that the syntactic sugar `in` makes the code more readable so:

```
m2.__contains__(k)
```

becomes

```
k in m2
```

---

Another usability point is that

```
>>> help(sherlockAndAnagrams)
Help on function sherlockAndAnagrams in module __main__:

sherlockAndAnagrams(s)
    # Complete the sherlockAndAnagrams function below.
```

is not very very useful, with the library `doctest` you can put your examples in a string under the function and they will both be run and be provided when you ask help on the function.

---

As a last point I am not sure but I think that the library `itertools` has something that would  very much help with the `sherlockAndAnagrams` function.

Comment: `k in m2` added now

Comment: Thanks Caridorc, didn't think the "in" would work for key value pairs but just for lists, coming from Java I thought the `__contains__` was the equivalent of `.contains()` for `Map` but indeed the `in` keyword makes the work and it's more beautiful to see :)